# Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ must be in the open set strings which covers the $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I read a book about the set theory and met with the following:
[image]

I really do not understand the notes in the parenthesis, is it means that the irrational number is very close to the rational number? And why $\sqrt{2}$ is so special irrational number? And how to prove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the paragraph is that you can make a countable union of intervals that covers all the rationals (or any countable set of points we want) but has very small total length.  The point of the parenthetical note is to counteract the feeling some people have that all the irrationals must be covered as well because they are very close to rationals.  There is nothing special about $\sqrt 2$ except that it is irrational.  Depending upon the $\epsilon$ chosen and the order we list the rationals in, it might be covered, but it is not guaranteed.  Their point is that you cannot prove $\sqrt 2$ (or any other number not in $A$) is covered by any of the intervals.